# capistrano seems to skip all its tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

When I run `cap env deploy` none of the steps run. What would I do to even begin debugging what the issue is. I'm not sure if its related but `time bin/cap -T` takes `real 1m24.202s` to run.

```
ruby -v: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
gem -v: 2.5.1
```

Even checking capistranos version number takes 45 seconds

```
# time bin/cap --version
Capistrano Version: 3.5.0 (Rake Version: 12.0.0)

real    0m42.940s
```

This is the output of `cap deploy`:

```
root@f9befa5efa56:~/lrnz# bin/cap --trace=stdout autoqa deploy
** Invoke autoqa (first_time)
** Execute autoqa
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_linked_dirs
** Invoke rbenv:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:map_bins
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:check_lock (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:check_git (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check_git
** Execute deploy:check_lock
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
** Execute git:check
** Invoke deploy:check:directories (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:directories
** Invoke deploy:secrets (first_time)
** Execute deploy:secrets
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:check:make_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:set_previous_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_previous_revision
** Invoke deploy:started (first_time)
** Execute deploy:started
** Invoke deploy:updating (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:new_release_path (first_time)
** Execute deploy:new_release_path
** Invoke slack:deploy:updating (first_time)
** Execute slack:deploy:updating
** Invoke deploy:deploy_info (first_time)
** Execute deploy:deploy_info
00:00 deploy:deploy_info
      >> Deploying master to autoqa
** Execute deploy:updating
** Invoke git:create_release (first_time)
** Invoke git:update (first_time)
** Invoke git:clone (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper
** Execute git:clone
** Execute git:update
** Execute git:create_release
** Invoke deploy:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_current_revision
** Invoke git:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute git:set_current_revision
** Invoke deploy:symlink:shared (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:shared
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:set_current_branch (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_current_branch
** Invoke deploy:updated (first_time)
** Invoke bundler:install (first_time)
** Execute bundler:install
** Execute deploy:updated
** Invoke deploy:compile_assets (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env
** Execute deploy:compile_assets
** Invoke deploy:assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute deploy:assets:precompile
** Invoke deploy:assets:s3upload (first_time)
** Execute deploy:assets:s3upload
** Invoke deploy:assets:backup_manifest (first_time)
** Execute deploy:assets:backup_manifest
** Invoke deploy:cleanup_assets (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env
** Execute deploy:cleanup_assets
** Invoke deploy:normalize_assets (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env
** Execute deploy:normalize_assets
** Invoke deploy:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env
** Execute deploy:migrate
** Invoke es:check (first_time)
** Execute es:check
** Invoke deploy:publishing (first_time)
** Execute deploy:publishing
** Invoke deploy:symlink:release (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:release
** Invoke deploy:published (first_time)
** Execute deploy:published
** Invoke deploy:finishing (first_time)
** Execute deploy:finishing
** Invoke deploy:cleanup (first_time)
** Execute deploy:cleanup
** Invoke slack:deploy:updated (first_time)
** Execute slack:deploy:updated
** Invoke deploy:finished (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:permissions (first_time)
** Execute deploy:permissions
** Invoke deploy:restart (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:secrets
** Execute deploy:restart
** Execute deploy:finished
** Invoke deploy:log_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:log_revision
** Invoke notify:logentries (first_time)
** Execute notify:logentries
** Invoke notify:newrelic (first_time)
** Execute notify:newrelic
** Invoke notify:release_notes (first_time)
** Execute notify:release_notes
```

Comment: I am guessing that autoqa is your environment. Could you also post your deploy.rb and autoqa.rb files?

Comment: @Jeremie I've uploaded both files here. https://gist.github.com/davidneudorfer/0ecbfe01be905420be0444627fc48bc4

Comment: I don't see any roles or servers to deploy to... Is this set somewhere else?

Comment: As you can tell I'm not the most familiar with capistrano. I'm reviewing the capistrano docs now.

Comment: I updated my answer to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the stage to the command

`cap production deploy` for production

**UPDATE**

It seems your deploy docs are missing the roles or servers to deploy to. You can find [more info here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano#server-roles).

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my question. I am running `cap env deploy`. Thats why you see the output with all the tasks.

Comment: This is right. Capistrano had no where to run the tasks.